# Being rejected despite being more than capable for a role as a fresh grad

Tags: hiring-process, hiring

As a recent graduate who (fully) double majored in physics and in the pure and applied mathematics from a top 100 univeristy, I applied to a role with the following job description:

> Degree in any discipline
>
> Strong extra curriculum track record with excellent leadership  skills
>
> intelligent and articulate individual who can relate to and influence people at all levels
>
> possess excellent Microsoft Excel skills
>
> Detailed analytical abilities
>
> Modelling techniques and method

to realise I was rejected.

As a graduate in my major, I possess strong computational and mathematical modelling techniques in the physical science so picking up any business or financial modelling technique would be a breeze. Further, my competency in computational and mathematical is aided by a good demonstration of computer software like MatLab and Mathematica to allow me to perform every thing that MS Excel does but more computationally efficient.
It goes without saying that a graduate from both math and physics possess beyond strong analytical abilities.

In my short anecdotal experiences, I seem to be rejected for business and financial roles but short listed for technical roles in companies where technical skills are at the core of their operation and achievements. I have even been commended by a chief fellow at NASA for my background and was requested to send in my CV.

What are the possible reasons for which a candidate in my shoes may be rejected?

Comment: Any reason not to assume that they simply had at least one candidate who was more qualified than you?

Comment: Any attempts to answer would just be us speculating. Maybe you don't seem like a good cultural fit, or maybe you don't seem humble, mature or self-reflective enough, or they're looking for something specific in your background which wasn't there (like actual Excel experience), or there was a red flag, or maybe you're not as well-qualified as you seem to think, or you're *over*qualified, or (if you interviewed) maybe you screwed up a few technical or HR questions, or they might even just have found someone and stopped looking before they got to you.

Comment: Impossible to say. General categories for rejection are: they had better candidates, you're not as suited to the role as you think you are, or they simply didn't like you or your fit to the role/company. But there are hundreds of specific reasons in those categories and hundreds more that don't fit in those groups. Realise that job searching is a numbers game and move on.

Comment: Never EVER think you was wrong. I explain why. Now you are 22-25 something??? Imagine that in 20 years, you will be a guy that changed 3 jobs. With constantly increasing role/responsibility/salary. Trust me it will happen. How will the future you look back on the current you? It will look that way "some idi..ts rejected me, giving me a lot of other chances and opportunities." That's all! Trust me, it will happen. So...nothing is really bad in you, they s*ck! And it is probably because you are too strong or too strange for them ("strange" translated "too strong and will steal our jobs").

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, you were rejected for lack of "soft" skills such as "leadership" and "influence." Because if you had them, you would have "influenced" them to hire you. You may have them, but need to showcase them, possibly downplaying your "technical" skills.

Answer (score 3):

Your breakdown of why you are skilled enough to do the job sems to completely gloss over these two sections, which seem to be pretty important items for this job:

> Strong extra curriculum track record with *excellent leadership skills*
>
> intelligent and articulate individual *who can relate to and influence people at all levels*

Jobs in the financial sector often need a lot of soft skills, which they might not feel you have enough of.

Alternatively, they might have disagreed with your assessment that "picking up the required skills will be a breeze". (Or you haven't convinced them you'll be able to do it easily). Finance mostly isn't complicated, but there is an awful lot of it that you'll need to learn.

And finally, there is the simpler options: either they found someone who was an even better fit, or they consider you to be over-qualified for the job.

Comment: Thank you for providing further insights.
I have attached to my CV a link highlighting my proficiency in the modelling of physical systems (wave propagation, heat flow, particle density gradient due to mid-air explosion, etc) using MatLab and Mathematica which should convince them unless the projects itself are insufficient to articulate my abilities. I have also added my achievement of scoring distinctions in upper division economics in light of my bypassing the formal prerequisites - as part of my electives // broadening curriculum. How may I improve my position?

Comment: @Physkid 1. Try to make your CV stand out on its own better (e.g. maybe people wouldn't want to click on your link). 2. Apply to more places. Wondering why one company is not interested in you is counter-productive. Move on.

Answer (score 3):

> my competency in computational and mathematical is aided by a good demonstration of computer software like MatLab and Mathematica to allow me to perform every thing that MS Excel does but more computationally efficient

hinting this to most of the prospective employer sounds to them like a "hey, change your entire Excel based workflow just to accommodate for my brilliant capacity with MatLab!".

Together with soft skills you may lack or need to develop (as suggested in other answers), they need to be convinced that you fit in their organization, not that their organization can easily adapt to your way of working.

And don't forget, of course, that there can be other candidates more qualified than you.